# Not able to login using SQL Server and Laravel 8

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel-8

I am using SQL Server with Laravel 8. My users table name is Users (letter u in caps) and I have following columns: LoginID(nvarchar(50), not null its my Primary key, Password and Email (letter p,e in caps) and RowID(bigInt,not null) this is auto-incrementing column and some more columns..

I don't have a column named as name or username. When I try to login using the columns LoginID and Password. Log in is successful and I am redirected to dashboard page as well. But on dashboard page I am getting the following error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name. (SQL: select top 1 * from [Users] where [Users].[] = shareef)

This is my login method for your reference:

````
        $request  = $req->validate([
          'LoginID' => 'required|min:3|max:50',
          'Password' => 'required|min:6',
        ]);

        $user = User::where('LoginID','=', $req->LoginID)->first();
        $credentials = array('LoginID' =>$req->input('LoginID'), 'password'=>$req->input('Password') );
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            //$req->session()->regenerate();
            //dd(auth()->user());
            return redirect('dashboard')->with('success','Signed in Successfully');
        }
        //return redirect("login")->withSuccess('Login details are not valid');
        else{return back()->withErrors('Credential are not matching');}

    }```
````

Comment: `select top 1 * from [Users] where [Users].[] = shareef` seems to indicate that you have a string-concatenated query getting invoked from Laravel and it's not setting the name of the LoginID/Username column correctly. Nor is it quoting the actual comparison value correctly, that should be `'shareef'` inside apostrophes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added my loginMethod. I am able to login and I can see dd(auth()->user()) as well in controller method. Preblem is on dashboard.blade.php file. When I do {{auth()->user()}} in blade file. I get the above mentioned error.. like column is missing or empty